# Is there some experts based resources on self defense techniques?

Tags: self-defense, self-training

would you suggest some good expert based youtube channel or websites focused on basic self defense techniques?

Comment: This is a very broad and general question that will produce endless varieties of answers. Is there something specific that you are looking for? Have you researched anything yourself?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for tips on how to be safe, then I am a big fan of [Mark "Animal" MacYoung](http://www.nononsenseselfdefense.com/marcmacyoung.html)'s [No Nonsense Self Defence](http://www.nononsenseselfdefense.com/). It has a lot of good advice on self defence form prevention to running to safety to decreasing the risk of getting attacked. Also, the site highlights a lot of myths and rubbish which is branded as self defence.

If on the other hand, you are looking for the mythical fighting technique that will work all the time, be effective, and that you can learn from youtube... I have some bad news for you: it does not exist. The best you can expect is scammers and/or idiots.